# Basicity comparison between pyridine amines and other compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, amines

[image: 1: pyridin‐4‐amine; 2: pyridin‐3‐amine; 3: aniline; 4: 1,4,5,6‐tetrahydropyrimidine]

In cases **1**, **2**, **3**, the compounds will resonate, thus giving them more stability.

Firstly, **I want to know whether nitrogen has a +M effect**? (due to it having a lone pair of electrons?)

In case **1**, resonance occurs and the electron density above the $\ce{NH2}$ group is delocalised, even in the cases **2**, and **3**, this is true. But in **1** the $\ce{N}$ is at the *para*-position, while in **2** the $\ce{N}$ is at the *meta*-position. How would that affect the order?

It would help if someone could hint at the factors coming into play here.

Case **4** is non-resonating, so it would be the most basic, right? How do I arrange the rest in order?

Comment: The pyridine nitrogen does not involve in resonance but is boosted by para activation by the amine group. So, 1 is more basic than 2 since amine boosts ortho and para positions more than meta. We can put 3 to the end of the list. You are right about 4 being the most basic because there are just two conjugation structures which imply the lone pair is available more easily than 1 or 2 or 3. Hence I would go with 4>1>2>3.

Comment: @SurajS Could you please show the 2 conjugation structures of 4? I thought that there would be no resonance at all in 4.